# Why define type of instance var in the __construct rather than in the var list?

Tags: php, oop

I am reading some code that looks like that:

Class_Menu.php:

```
<?php
    class Menu {
        private $label;
        private $link;
        private $args;

        function __construct($label, $link, $args=array()) {
            $this->label=$label;
            $this->link=$link;
            $this->args=$args;
        }
...
```

Note how `$args` is defined as an array in the `__construct`.  Why would one choose this approach rather than define `$args` in the var list:

```
<?php
    class Menu {
        private $label;
        private $link;
        private $args=array();

        function __construct($label, $link, $args) {
            $this->label=$label;
            $this->link=$link;
            $this->args=$args;
        }
...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the first example, `$args` is optional. The constructor can be called with only 2 arguments for `$label` and `$link`, and `$args` will be defined as an empty array.

In the second example, the `$args` parameter is required.

(opinion): I would have left `$args = array()` in the constructor AND when declaring the property so it's easy to tell at a glance what type of var $args is.

```
<?php
    class Menu {
        private $label;
        private $link;
        private $args = array();

        function __construct($label, $link, $args=array()) {
            $this->label=$label;
            $this->link=$link;
            $this->args=$args;
        }
```

Comment: To go even further, use a type hint. `__construct($label, $link, array $args = array())`

Comment: @BoltClock: why would you use a type hint? What do you gain? Just curious.

Comment: @PeeHaa: [Typehint (PHP Manual)](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php) will ensure that only arrays are passed for that parameter. Otherwise there will be an exception thrown.

Comment: @PeeHaa: The OP apparently wants to define its type — since it's only (so far) settable by the constructor, a type hint would be nice to ensure that it's an array.

Answer (score 2):

One allows you to use the constructor with either two or three arguments (as the third is *optional*).

The other does not.

Why not read [the manual entry on function arguments](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php)?

Answer (score 2):

That just makes `$args` optional. If the constructor's called as `new Menu('a', 'b')`, then args will be defined as an empty array and not raise an error about the missing argument.